# Error with adding users into the json file

Tags: python, json, database, discord, discord.py

I'm writing a discord bot for multiple servers. The bot has a system of levels and economy. Started writing economy. Faced the problem of writing the code for adding a user by id to the database. Command code for adding a user to the database:

```
async def add(ctx, mem: discord.Member):


     
     with open("servers.json", "r") as f:
          
          data = json.load(f)
          lang = data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['oth']['lang']
          users = data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['eco']['users']
          userid = data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['eco']['users'][str(mem.id)]

     if str(ctx.message.guild.id) in data:
          if lang == 'ru':

               data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['eco']['users'].append({str(mem.id):{}})
               with open("servers.json", "w") as f:
                    json.dump(data, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

               await ctx.send('Success')
          else:
               await ctx.send('Language error')
     else:
          await ctx.send('This server is not in the database')
```

Json file:

```
    "988095856215461928": {
        "cd": {
            "ban": 60,
            "casino": 10,
            "fifty": 10,
            "mute": 10,
            "rob": 3600,
            "unban": 60,
            "unmute": 10,
            "unwarn": 10,
            "warn": 10,
            "work": 3600
        },
        "eco": {
            "eco_emoji": ":coin:",
            "shop": {
                "id": {
                    "cost": 100,
                    "name": "",
                    "role_id": ""
                }
            },
            "users": {
                "459007192276795393": {
                    "bank": 0,
                    "inv": {},
                    "money": 0
                }
            }
        },
        "oth": {
            "lang": "ru"
        },
        "pay": {
            "eco1": "false",
            "eco2": "false",
            "extra": "false",
            "logs": "false"
        },
        "roles": {
            "muterole": "None"
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to add a user, I get this error:

```
Command raised an exception: KeyError: '988839445392408616'
```

There is only me in the json file, in the bot code there is a command to add a server to the database, when using the command, I am added to the file, but when using the command to add another user, problems arise. How can I make a command to add a user to the economy database?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: it seems it doesn't have key `988839445392408616` so you should first check `if str(ctx.message.guild.id) in data:` before you get `lang =  ...` , etc.

Answer (score 0):

Error may suggets that you don't have key `988839445392408616` in your `data` and you have to check key before you get `lang = ...`, etc.

```
with open("servers.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

if str(ctx.message.guild.id) in data:  # <--- check `key` before you get `lang`, etc.

    lang = data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['oth']['lang']
    users = data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['eco']['users']
    userid = data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]['eco']['users'][str(mem.id)]

    # ... other code ...
else:
     await ctx.send('This server is not in the database')

#else:  # <--- create new `key` in `data`
#    data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)] = {'oth':{'lang':""}, 'eco': {'users':""})
```

Comment: Sorry, but you misunderstood me a little. This server is in the database, id "988839445392408616" is the user id. When I add it to the database I get the above error. The text of the error above, it does not contain much text in itself with the words "Traceback" and other, just what I wrote.

Comment: I don't see any database in your code but only JSON file. And this code can give error `KeyError` only in one place - in `lang = data[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]....` when `str(ctx.message.guild.id)` doesn't exists in `data`. And this needs code which I saw in answer. You have to check `if str(ctx.message.guild.id) in data:` before you try to get `lang = ... ` and `users = ...`, etc.